# Scipy optimize minimize not reliable

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, mathematical-optimization

My program:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import itertools
from scipy.optimize import minimize

global width
width = 0.3

def time_builder(f, t0=0, tf=300):
    return list(np.round(np.arange(t0, tf, 1/f*1000),3))

def duo_stim_overlap(t1, t2):
    """
    Function taking 2 timelines build by time_builder function in input
    and returning the ids of overlapping pulses between the 2.
    len(t1) < len(t2)
    """    
    pulse_id_t1 = [x for x in range(len(t1)) for y in range(len(t2)) if abs(t1[x] - t2[y]) < width]
    pulse_id_t2 = [x for x in range(len(t2)) for y in range(len(t1)) if abs(t2[x] - t1[y]) < width]

    return pulse_id_t1, pulse_id_t2

def optimal_delay(s):
    frequences = [20, 60, 80, 250, 500]
    t0 = 0
    tf = 150

    delay = 0                           # delay between signals, 
    timelines = list()
    overlap = dict()

    for i in range(len(frequences)):
        timelines.append(time_builder(frequences[i], t0+delay, tf))
        overlap[i] = list()
        delay += s

    for subset in itertools.combinations(timelines, 2):
        p1_stim, p2_stim = duo_stim_overlap(subset[0], subset[1])
        overlap[timelines.index(subset[0])] += p1_stim
        overlap[timelines.index(subset[1])] += p2_stim

    optim_param = 0
    for key, items in overlap.items():
        optim_param += (len(list(set(items)))/len(timelines[key]))

    return optim_param

res = minimize(optimal_delay, 1.5, method='Nelder-Mead', tol = 0.01, bounds = [(0, 5)], options={'disp': True})
```

So my goal is to minimize the value `optim_param` computed by the function optimal_delay.
First of all, gradient methods don't do anything. They stop at the first iteration.
Second, I would need to set bounds for the s value of optimal delay (between 0 and 5 for instance). I know it's not possible with the Nelder-Mead simplex method, but the others didn't work at all.
Third, I don't really know how to set the parameter tol for termination. Bot `tol = 0.01` and `tol = 0.0000001` didn' t gave me good result. (and really close ones).
And finally if I start at 1.8 for instance, the minimize function gives me a value far from being a minimum...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you plot your optimal_delay function you'll see that it's far from convex. The search will just find any local minima close to your starting point.[image]

Comment: Yeah definitely... Right now my solution is a brute force approach where I test all s value in `shifts = np.arange(0, (1/max(frequences))*1000+0.05, 0.05)`.  I'm checking far too many possibilities right now, and the computation starts to take really a long time... Do you have any suggestion on how I could proceed to find a s value satisfying enough in a minimum amount of operation?

Comment: @Mathieu: Divide the range into, say, 100 intervals, run the minimization separately for all the intervals, pick the best one? That's not guaranteed to find the global minima, but might get you reasonably close, if that's good enough for you.

Comment: And it will be indeed faster... Thanks!

Comment: Many people seem to think that minimization routines are magic. You have shown that is indeed not the case. Sigh.